# DotNet Core Console Application: AutoMapper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, automapper

Hello I am using AutoMapper in DotNet Core Console Application

StartUp file:

```
public class StartUp
{
    public  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {  
    services.AddAutoMapper();  
}  
}
```

Mapping File:

```
public class MappingProfile: Profile {  
    public MappingProfile() {  
         CreateMap < Employee, EmployeeModel > ().ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => new Address {  
            City = src.City, State = src.State   }));  
    }  
}
```

UnitTest Class:

```
 public class UnitTest1
    {
         private readonly IMapper _mapper;  
        public UnitTest1(IMapper mapper)
        {
             _mapper = mapper;  
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {  

            Employee  emp = new Employee ();  
            emp.Id=1;
            emp.Name="Test";
           var empmodel = _mapper.Map < Employee, EmployeeModel > (emp);  
           Assert.Equal(empmodel.Name,"Test");
            Assert.Equal(empmodel.Id,1);

        }
    }
```

Reference Link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-automapper-in-asp-net-core-mvc-application/

I am Getting below error on running test file: 
Error Message:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture
>   data: IMapper mapper

Thank you

Comment: You don't normally use DI in your tests, you simply create the mapper yourself.

Answer (score 4):

It’s not quite clear to me exactly what you are trying to do, but if you use the automapper in a test project, then it might be useful:

```
[Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {

        var employee = new Employee
        {
            AddressEmployee = new Address
            {
                City = "SomeCity"
            }
        };

        //initialize automapper and register mapping profile
        var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new EmployeeProfile()));

        //create new mapper
        var mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();

        //map
        var employeeModel = mapper.Map<EmployeeModel>(employee);

        // do assert or another stuff
    }
```

By the way, if the names of the fields in the classes are the same, you do not need to specify from where and to what map. It is enough to specify the classes.

```
CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your unit tests are not starting up the same as you normally would, your dependency injection is not set up or being used. So when your unit tests run you get a null reference exception because no-one is passing in Imapper.

If you want to use a constructor I'm your unit tests you will want to do

```
public test() {
    _mapper = new Mapping profile();
}
```

Then you would have an instance of the object you're trying to test. In unit tests I try to avoid calling the abstraction of the class I'm trying to test because I'm testing the actual workings of that class behind the interface